# is it still possible to get the gratitude crystal from Peater?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I think I might have skipped talking to Peater to advance the side quest and Peater keeps saying "Bamboo slivers!  Who has gone and stolen my baby girl's heart?  Oh... I knew this day would come, but..." and Peatrice keeps saying " Darling!  I told you that we need to keep our relationship secret!  If you come over too often, my dad will catch on to us!  what could you possibly want this late?"  and it gives me a choice of answering deposit items, Need to talk!, or nothing and any way I answer it they say the same thing every time and I cannot find anything online that would help me.  I am thinking that I completely messed it up and that I cannot get the crystals. is it still possible to get the crystals or is it now immposible to get them?

Comment: Can you be a little more precise as to the steps you did and what they're saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete details on getting all Gratitude Crystals are listed in the GameFaqs FAQ [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/faqs/63386).  None are missable, per discussions [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960633-/61312402) and [here](http://www.zeldauniverse.net/forums/skyward-sword/138124-permanently-missable-items-in-skyward-sword.html).

You would be most interested in section 3.10 of the FAQ "Crush or be Crushed?"

> Start flirting with Peatrice early on in the game once she has the "quest
>   bubble" above her head. As you progress, Peater(Bamboo Island) will tell you
>   he thinks that someone is trying to take his "baby girl" from him and asks you
>   to get rid of him. Speak to Peatrice and either break off the connection or
>   tell her you like her. If you choose to break it off, speak to Peater and he
>   will reward you with 5 Gratitude Crystals. If you choose to like Peatrice, she
>   will reward you with 5 Gratitude Crystals.

Comment: Not to be rude or anything but I have looked online and I know how to do the quest but I never saw anybody skip the text bubble over Peater's head in any video and I think I did skip over it because when I talk to Peater he never asks me to get rid of the person trying to take his "baby girl" and there is never a text bubble over his head.

Comment: I'm not offended, just trying to be helpful.  There is always the possibility it is a bug, but I didn't find any reports of one when I researched.  I'll take another look when I get a chance.

Comment: It is not really important to get this because I have 80 out of the 85 crystals that there are and the number you need to get the best reward is 80 so I don't need it but I would like to get it because I would like to try and 100% the game, and if you cannot find anything on it that is O.K. I will just get it in Hero Mode.  I really appreciate the research that you are doing for me and any one else that has this problem.

Comment: @Sean - As far as I know there's only 80 crystals in the first place.  So if you have 80, then you got the crystals from this quest.

Comment: The 80 crystal cap is established [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/answers?qid=308445) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/answers?qid=305828).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you already resolved the quest without ever talking to Peater and got your five crystals from Peatrice. See if the #Ending-A dialogue here rings a bell (contains dialogue spoilers for the game):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/63355259?page=3

Comment: You can post the spoilers here instead of just linking to an outside source by using the "spoiler" markup.  Details on how to do this can be found [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).